# How to automate porting process from chrome extension to edge?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, automation, microsoft-edge-extension

I am familiar with Microsoft Extension Toolkit - but i'm looking for some command line tool that can convert the chrome extension to edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my searching result. At present, there is no any other way available to port a Chrome extension to Edge.

Currently we cannot do automate porting using any command line tool because no such commands or tool exists to fulfill this requirement.

You have to use Microsoft Extension Toolkit for porting an extension.

Ref: [Porting an extension from Chrome to Microsoft Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/guides/porting-chrome-extensions)